# how set the border color property through a class name using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I can set the border color property through using the jquery css method but when reading the border color property back through IE and Firefox, I get different format values. To get around this issue, I add a class name including the border color like this:

```
$('#'+ pageSection[sectionIndex] +'').addClass("addBordeColor");

.addBorderColor
{
    border: 2px color black;
}
```

This is not working properly. Any ideas on how troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Please rephrase the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By fixing the syntax error:

Replace

```
$("#" +pageSection[sectionIndex]").addClass("addBordeColor")
```

with

```
$("#" +pageSection[sectionIndex]).addClass("addBorderColor")
```